# How do i use loops to get it to read each line at a time in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf

I have a text file like,

```
01_AA_00 11
02_BB_00 11
03_CC_01 22
04_BB_01 22
05_CC_02 33
06_CC_02 33
```

Expected output in a new file is,

```
01_AA_00 11 AABBCCDD
02_AA_00 11 AABBCCDD
03_AA_01 22 AABBCCDD
04_BB_01 22 AABBCCDD
05_CC_02 33 AABBCCDD
06_CC_02 33 AABBCCDD
```

What i have been trying to do,

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    fName=$(awk '{print $1}' $1)
    printf "$fName AABBCCDD\n" > nFile.txt
done < $1
```

the output i am getting is like this,

```
01_AA_00 11
02_BB_00 11
03_CC_01 22
04_BB_01 22
05_CC_02 33
06_CC_02 33 AABBCCDD
```

I not looking to just add text after the each line, where i know that it could be done like so `awk '{print $0, "AABBCCDD"}' file.txt > nFile.txt` since i have to use other information stored in variables.

Comment: You say you are "not looking to just add text after the each line" but the "Expected output in a new file" example you provide shows exactly that. Please provide a clearer example of the problem.

Comment: Note that by using a bash while loop to read each line of the file and then running awk **on the entire file** (you aren't using the `line` variable you created), you are performing O(n^2) operations. You should be aiming for O(n) - ie. proportional to the number of lines in the file and not the square of the number of lines.

Comment: Also, you overwrite `nFile.txt` each time through the loop. Perhaps you meant to append?

Comment: @jhnc Yeah, append is what I meant. and okay i see i haven't used the line variable, i look at it

Comment: Instead of reading the line into a string, and then using `awk`  to tear the spring apart, consider using `readarray` instead of `read`, which would already split the line into words and put the consitutent words into an array. The command itself is described in the section _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_ of the bash man page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
 echo $line" AABBCCDD" >> nFile.txt;
done < $1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk` only

```
awk -v v="AABBCCDD" '{print $0 " " v}' file.txt > nFile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

just leverage `ORS` ::

```
{m,g}awk 1 ORS=' AABBCCDD\n'

01_AA_00 11 AABBCCDD
02_BB_00 11 AABBCCDD
03_CC_01 22 AABBCCDD
04_BB_01 22 AABBCCDD
05_CC_02 33 AABBCCDD
06_CC_02 33 AABBCCDD
```

another way is to use `OFS` instead ::

```
 {m,g}awk ++NF FS='^$' OFS=' AABBCCDD'
```

Answer (score -1):

A `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/$/ AABBCCDD/' file.txt > nFile.txt
```